# Loading Javascript & HTML in webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'm having some trouble with getting Javascript to work in a Webview. Basically, what I'm doing is using a Webview Client and then loading an html file there:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test/test.html");
```

The Webview loads perfectly and the html is displayed without problem.

In the html file, to load the javascript file I use

```
<script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

The Javascript file is also in the assets folder. The html/javascript works fine running it in a normal browser in my laptop, but I just can't get it to work in the Android. I've tried running it without setting a WebView client but no luck either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the full path reference to the javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion! Change your folder sturcture to

```
 .../assets/www
```

Then try to put your js into a folder called "lib". .../assets/www/lib

then try the code like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/test.js"></script>
```

change

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/test.html");
```

Comment: Why do you suggest these changes?